# Convert 2D meshgrid into a 3D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have coordinates (lat, lon) in a meshgrid, and data asociated with each "point".
I want to export into a .csv and have each point asociated with the data i want to analyze. So far, my code looks like this.

```
xx1,yy1=np.meshgrid(xx,yy)
row_format = np.stack([z.ravel() for z in (xx1, yy1, data['Hs'])], axis=1)
print(row_format)
pd.DataFrame(row_format).to_csv('sample.csv')
```

The data is in a dataframe that has a certain order. But the output is as follows:

| x | y | Hs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 265 | 19 | 0 |
| 266 | 19 | 1 |
| 267 | 19 | 2 |

And it should be as follows, in order to make sense with the data order:

| x | y | Hs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 265 | 19 | 0 |
| 265 | 18 | 1 |
| 265 | 17 | 2 |

I only need to make the "x" column to be the one with the "still" value while the "y" column goes through its values ("x" will change value once every "y" value has been written). Anyone know how to change that order? Or another way to get my desired output?

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry, english is not my native language and i don´t really understand, do you want me to add a code that can be run or my csv output file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, you could do the following. Some notes:

- `y_cycle` currently goes from 19 to 1 inclusive (so 19 values total). Change the 0 to -1 in the `np.arange` statement if you want a total of 20 values before y cycles back to the beginning.
- The final 2 lines replace the `x` and `y` columns in your current `df`. If you want the new `x` and `y` values (stored in `repeated_x` and `repeated_y` to be new columns, you can change `df["x"]` to a different column name, and same for `df["y"]`.

```py
y_cycle = np.arange(19, 0, -1)
length_y_cycle = len(y_cycle)
x_start = 265
length = len(df)

num_y_cycles = int(math.ceil(length / length_y_cycle))
repeated_y = np.tile(y_cycle.reshape(1, length_y_cycle), num_y_cycles)[0][:length]

x_fin = x_start + num_y_cycles - 1
repeated_x = np.repeat(np.arange(x_start, x_fin+1, 1), length_y_cycle)[:length]

df["x"] = repeated_x
df["y"] = repeated_y
```

Let me know if you have any questions.